# convergence of $\int_{\Bbb R^2} \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{(1+x^2+y^2)^\alpha}dxdy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

For what values of $\alpha$ does the following improper integral converges?

$$\int_{\Bbb R^2} \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{(1+x^2+y^2)^\alpha}dxdy$$

I tried to change to polar coordinates and look at the absolute value of the integral. It seems like the answer should be $\alpha >1$ but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Call your integral $I(\alpha)$. Indeed, polar coordinates allows us to write this as:
$$\begin{align}I(\alpha)&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(r^2)}{(1+r^2)^\alpha}r~drd\theta\\&=\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(u)}{(1+u)^\alpha}~du\qquad u=r^2\implies du=2r~dr\end{align}$$
Can you find for what $\alpha$ the integral $$J(\alpha):=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(u)}{(1+u)^\alpha}~du$$
converges?

Comment: Shouldn't I put an absolute value over the sin? since the integral converges iff it absolutely converges

Comment: Convergence does not imply absolute convergence, but the converse is true. So if you can show absolute convergence then surely the integral converges. However this is not an "if and only if" type thing.